# Strings not selected properly in if comparison

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have the following code.

```
while True:

    # Prompt
    command = input("> ").upper()

    if command == "WEST" or "IN":
        if adventure.move(command) == True:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("You cannot go there")
    elif command == "QUIT":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid command")
```

The idea is to prompt the user for a command. If the command is either direction "WEST" or "IN" its supposed to move and give a description. This all works. The idea is that an adventure consists of several rooms a user must navigate through

For the record: adventure.move(command) returns True if the move was succesful, and False if the move could not be made. Because there was no direction to be going in, for example.

The problem is that if I give a command like QUIT or FOO I am expecting a different result. However, this does not happen.

```
>WEST
True (move successful)
>QUIT
You cannot go there
>FOO
You cannot go there
```

It seems that whatever I type; it will always accept the first if statement.

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your first if statement to this

```
while True:

    # Prompt
    command = input("> ").upper()

    if command == "WEST" or command == "IN":
        if adventure.move(command) == True:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("You cannot go there")
    elif command == "QUIT":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid command")
```

`if command == "WEST" or "IN":` will always evalutate to true because it is actually asking if command is equal to west or the equivalent of  `bool("IN")` which it will always return true unless it is an empty string. And in an or statement if either of the logic tests return true then the code will be executed in the if block.

Comment: You're right.

I thought I had another solution at first, but yours is the only one who does the trick.

Thanks again